# Agregar un dato a un array el cual no esta en la base de datos pero la otra información si viene de base de datos de un select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Tengo una tabla con un select el cual me trae una informacion de la base de datos, agrego un dato "Por Definir" que no esta en la base de datos pero me aparecen repetido en el select, como puedo hacer para que solo me aparezca una vez?

```
        await api
          .get('select_nodos')
          .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.data) {
              optCDI.length = 0;
              response.data.data.map((element: Nodos) => {
                optCDI.push({
                  value: element.Id_cdi,
                  label: element.nemotecnico,
                });
              });
              response.data.data.map(() => {
                optCDI.push({
                  value: 0,
                  label: 'Por definir',
                });
              });
            }
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            controlError(error);
          });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes agregar el valor que no está en la base de datos antes de llenar el array con la consulta API, por ejemplo:

```
data{
  return(){
    optCDI: [{value: 0, label: 'Por definir'}],
  }
}
```

Cuando llames a la api solo haces el push de los demás valores.

Si no quieres agregarlo al inicio en la declaración, entonces solo puedes hacer el push del valor de la siguiente manera:

```
await api
      .get('select_nodos')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.data.data) {
          optCDI.length = 0;
          response.data.data.map((element: Nodos) => {
            optCDI.push({
              value: element.Id_cdi,
              label: element.nemotecnico,
            });
          });
            this.optCDI.push({
              value: 0,
              label: 'Por definir',
            });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        controlError(error);
      });
```

De esta forma se agregará al final de todos los valores insertados previamente.

Ahora, porque se te repite los valores tal cual como está tu código, es porque estás recorriendo toda la respuesta y haciendo un push por cada iteración.

Comment: muchas, muchas, muchas gracias